# How to make button occupy gridview?

Tags: android, button, gridview

I am developing a project where one button will occupy two or more cells in a gridview. Is that possible? What I initially did was using imageadapter but it's limited to one cell each in the gridview. Thank you.

Comment: whats the point if you are using grid view then display the button outside of the grid view.

Comment: I'm actually creating a battleship game for our school project. I have a gridview then the buttons will be the ships.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after reading your comment I suggest you use SurfaceView. It is more fitting for your game.
Here is a good [game tutorial for beginners](http://www.edu4java.com/androidgame.html).
Just replace the images with your battleships.